# Notation for a Self-Map

Tags: notation

Is there a standard notation for a self map? i.e. for a map
$$f : U \rightarrow U$$
We can describe $f$ in words as a **map on $U$** or a **self-map on $U$**.

But is there an accepted mathematical notation for this that doesn't involve writing $U$ twice? Maybe a kind of hooked arrow like this:

$$f : U \circlearrowleft$$

Except shaped more like the $\supset$ symbol. I wasn't able to find anything with a quick Google search, and couldn't find anything appropriate on [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: A "self-map" $f$ is an endomorphism. A possible notation for that would be $f\in End(U)$.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to do this symbolically. What is so wrong with $f\colon U\to U$? I personally think you should avoid as much as you can to introduce unnecessary notation.

Comment: @Shoutre - it can become messy when the space $U$ is written explicitly as a long expression.

Comment: Then you could for instance set, say $C$ as a short for your complicated space and still write $f\colon C\to C$. I believe this is more or less standard. My point is that I think there is no standard symbolic way of doing this.